Automation to Convert Mac to Windows Paths
I'm migrating to MacOS but most of my organisation works with Windows. We frequently exchange links (via email / teams) to a network drive mapped to "D:\".
I am exploring an automation to convert MacOS filepaths to Windows filepaths using a small python script.
Expected Behaviour
Select Text -> Right-Click -> Services -> AutomationName -> Text gets replaced.
[EDIT: I can tell that the Automation is working because the text does get replaced. The issue is that it gets replaced with "Input", which is being passed onto Python as a string ("Input").
Issue

Cannot pass the "Selected Text" as a variable onto the python function.
The python function is working as expected in terminal.

Steps so far

# Convert MacOS Path to Windows Path

import sys

def MtW(link):
    wPath = link.replace("/Users/FF/Server","D:\\").replace("/","\\")
    print(wPath)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]](sys.argv[2])


Thank you for your support.

It calls function MtW ("sys.argv[1]") (first item specified after calling .py) and passes variable Input ("sys.argv[2]") onto the function. -> Please see command specified in Automator

I found the solution for this. Perhaps it can be helpful to others.
The selected text gets stored in a variable called "$1/".
In case it helps anyone - here it is:

